# How do I stop my Command line closing in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Hi I'm creating a calculator and my code just keeps skipping to the end here's my code

```
// Calculator.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>


int num1, num2, ans, oper(0);



int main()
{
    std::cout << "Put in your first number to be calculated" <<std::endl;
    std::cin >> num1;
    std::cout << "Put in your second number to be calculated"<<std::endl;
    std::cin >> num2;
    std::cout << "The next bit is abit complicated, blame the code writer for that he cant use char yet but anyway." << std::endl;
std::cout << "If you want multiplication press 1 then enter." << std::endl;
std::cout << "If you want division prees 2 then enter." << std::endl;
std::cout << "If you want addition press 3 then enter." << std::endl;
std::cout << "If you want subtraction press 4 then enter." << std::endl;
std::cin.get();
if (oper == 1) {
    ans = num1*num2;
    std::cout << ans;
}
while (oper == 2) {
    ans = num1 / num2;
    std::cin.get();
    std::cout << ans;
    std::cin.get();
}
while (oper == 3) {
    ans = num1 + num2;
    std::cout << ans;
    std::cin.get();
}
    while (oper == 4) {
        ans = num1 - num2;
        std::cout << ans;
        std::cin.get();
        }
return 0;
}
```

I'm looking for solutions for this can anyone help me, I am sorry if this a easy question I am new to C++

Comment: Code doesn't "skip to the end". Load up your debugger and observe your lines being executed and what their results are. And you may want to look into how to clear error flags and skip past the newline in your input stream...

Comment: Did you initialize `oper` with `0` to get rid of a compiler warning? Than look for a different solution to fix that warning.

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to do something with `oper`. Might be more than one thing, even.

Answer (score 2):

Try to write **system("pause");** before **return 0;** at the end of your program and press ctrl + F5.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
std::cin.get();
if (oper == 1) 
    ans = num1*num2;
else if(oper == 2)
    ans = num1 / num2;
else if(oper == 3) 
    ans = num1 + num2;
else if(oper == 4) 
    ans = num1 - num2;

std::cout << ans;     
std::cin.get();//this will block and prevent the console from closing until you press a key
return 0;
```